# setting z-index jquery ui controls?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, z-index

Annoyingly, the jquery ui's set a few css properties inline, making it impossible to override them in the stylesheet. I tried to override the values with jquery, but then they get changed back as soon as the control is interacted with.

Does anyone know if any of the jquery ui control's initialisers/constructors have the ability to override their z-index value or set other css properties?

Comment: perhaps "!important" could help, although it isn't the best way of doing it. you can use it like this: "position:relative!important;".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the jquery ui source code, the jquery ui functions generally contain the line `$(input).zIndex()`. Therefore, setting a z-index on the elements you are passing to the jquery ui function/control initialiser will work.

Comment: Can you clarify how you would pass the z-index value? For instance, if I'm initializing autocomplete, $("#search").autocomplete({source: items.json, minLength: 2}); where does the zIndex value get passed?